# log4j2 does not log in child process

Tags: java, linux, bash, log4j2

**Problem Description:** I have two .jar program and they can both write log files properly when they run individually. However, when I run one program and inside that program, I use command line to run the second program. The second program will not record log (it does not even create log files and directories).
Then if I run that first program using a bash script, both program do not record logs.

I am wondering why does that happen, and how can I make both of them recording log when started by bash. Please ask for more details if you need any. Thank you for your help in advance!

By the way, if you have any other suggestions involving coding styles please do so as I am a beginner and love to learn more.

**System Environment:**

```
Linux version 4.9.59-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017
```

**The bash script I used to start program 1:**

```
cd {path_to_the_jar}
java -jar PROGRAM_PARENT.jar &
exit 0
```

**The code section I used in program 1 to start program 2:**

```
public static void startProgram(int index){

    //store the command line to start a new program.
    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList();
    commandList.add("java");
    commandList.add("-jar");
    commandList.add(CHILD_PROGRAM_NAME[index]); //the name of the child program

    //start the child process using processBuilder
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        processHashMap.put(KEY_NAME[index], p); //store the process for future monitoring
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

**The logging package I used in both program:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**log4j2.xml in the Parent program:**

```
<configuration status="DEBUG" monitorInterval="30">
    <appenders>
        <console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
        </console>

        <File name="log" fileName="log/test.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </File>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileDebug" fileName="${sys:user.home}/logs/ParentProgram/debug.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:user.home}/logs/ParentProgram/$${date:yyyy-MM}/debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileError" fileName="${sys:user.home}/logs/ParentProgram/error.log"
                   filePattern="${sys:user.home}/logs/ParentProgram/$${date:yyyy-MM}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.mybatis" level="INFO"></logger>
        <root level="all">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileDebug"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:** I think I have figured out my problem. It was all because of the path to my log file (and my carelessness I guess). It contains `${sys:user.home}` so when you execute jar file with different user it will store to different folders.
Unfortunately when I execute them separately I use a normal user, but when I run them together I used the root user. Therefore I could not find the log in the folder of that normal user.
I think I should close it but I am not sure how to so if anyone know how to close this please do so or advise me.

Comment: You said, "they can both write log files properly when they run individually." Are you talking about when you run them in an IDE? Where is your log4j2.xml relative to your jar - is it inside one jar, inside both jars, external to both, etc? The log4j2.xml must be on the classpath so if it's not that could be the problem. Do you see an error messages when you run these programs?

Comment: Sorry for replying late.@D.B. They are  in both .jar files. My problem seems to happen because of ${sys:user.home} is used in my path. When I run them individually I use a normal user and when I ran them together(it is runned automatically when I start the system) it is using root user. So they are actually stored in different user path. Sorry that I did not check my settings correctly

Comment: That would explain a few things, glad you were able to figure it out. I believe the preferred method to "close" a question is to accept an answer as correct. I think in this case providing your own answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved and I have updated the result in the end of my question. I will quote it again here.

> Edit: I think I have figured out my problem. It was all because of the
>   path to my log file (and my carelessness I guess). It contains
>   ${sys:user.home} so when you execute jar file with different user it
>   will store to different folders. Unfortunately when I execute them
>   separately I use a normal user, but when I run them together I used
>   the root user. Therefore I could not find the log in the folder of
>   that normal user.

However there is one more thing to be added regarding my code. If you need to monitor multiple child processes you have to create new instances for both ProcessBuilder and Process. Using one ProcessBuilder object repeatedly will cause some problems iirc.